# Python:how to get keys with same values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From example, I have

```
[('Han Decane','12333'),('Can Decane','12333'),('Al Right','10110')]
```

the output should be

```
['Han Decane','Can Decane']
```

how can I get it?

Comment: Do you have a list of tuples, or an actual dictionary?

Comment: What if there are several groups of equal values?

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: Your dictionary is backwards.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your title specifies `keys`, but you gave a list of tuples as an example. Please edit.

Comment: I assume the given `list` would be passed to `dict()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this to work for any arbitrary key(s) you can use a defaultdict of OrderedDicts..

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict
result_dict = defaultdict(OrderedDict)
data = [('Han Decane','12333'),('Can Decane','12333'),('AlRight','10110')]
for (v,k) in data:
   result_dict[k][v]=True


>>> list(result_dict['12333'].keys())
['Han Decane', 'Can Decane']
```

And if you want all the results that had multiple values

```
>>> [k for k in result_dict if len(result_dict[k]) > 1 ]
['12333']
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want to avoid duplicates here. Otherwise using a list will be better.

Comment: Why an OrderedDict? And if you want to avoid duplicates, use a set.

Comment: Because otherwise you might get back `['Can Decane','Han Decane']` and the order might be important.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a map from the values to all the keys corresponding to those values

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = {'Han Decane':12333,'Can Decane':12333,'Al Right':10110}
map = defaultdict(list)
for i, j in map.iteritems():
    map[j].append(i)
```

this will create a dictionary of lists with the keys as the values of the old dict, and the values as a list of the corresponding old keys.

ie.

```
map[12333]
```

will be

```
['Han Decane','Can Decane']
```

Answer (score 0):

And another answer without all that fancy import stuff

```
data = [('Han Decane','12333'),('Can Decane','12333'),('AlRight','10110')]
result_dict = {}
for (v,k) in data: 
    if k not in result_dict:
        result_dict[k] = set()
    result_dict[k].add(v)

print(result_dict) # {'10110': {'AlRight'}, '12333': {'Han Decane', 'Can Decane'}}
print(list(result_dict['12333'])) # ['Can Decane', 'Han Decane']
```